# Calculating MOS, Jitter and R-Factor using Java

Tags: java, voip, rtp

I need to calculate the VOIP quality by sending synthetic calls between two hosts (2 Java Processes). I should find out the MOS, Jitter and R-Factor (VOIP Quality metrics). Based on the research so far, I found out that I should send RTP stream between two hosts and compute the above mentioned metrics. I couldn't find an example or a library that I can use to send RTP data using java and more precisely a library that can compute those metrics. Any help in this is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the jitter, latency and packet loss from the receiver reports in your RTCP packets.

The R-Factor can be calculated from those RTCP values as decribed in the [G.107](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-G.107) standard.

MOS is a subjective scale that you can't measure, but there are known MOS values for certain audio codecs.